# Button becomes invisible on its click

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a button and I make it visible =false when, I declared it.
But when the page loads, in the pre-render function, I make it visible=true. And it works fine, but when I click on the button(Insert), the button again becomes invisible, but I want that button to be visible.

```
<asp:Button ID="InsertButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" CommandName="Insert" Visible="false"
                        Text="Insert"  />

 protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         Button btValue = (Button)FormView1.FindControl("InsertButton");
            if (btValue != null)
        {
            btValue.Visible = true; //IT COMES HERE, WHEN I DEBUG
        }
    }
```

As the page loads, the button becomes visible, but as soon as i click insert button, it becomes invisible.

Comment: It seems like somewhere else in code you are setting its visibility back to `False`.

Comment: Try to debug your code, by declaratively setting the visibility of the button to `True`. What happens in this case once you press on it?

Comment: But you can do this same thing on page load with (!postback).

Comment: The thing, is I have 2 buttons and I want only 1 button at the run time to be visible. So, if I keep Visible=True, when I declare, on page load only 1 button is visible and as i click on the button, both the buttons become visible.

Comment: @rushankshah No, I cannot because, I have something which I need to bind first. So this code only works If it is written in Pre-Render.

Answer (score 2):

What is happening is you have wirrten code in Page_Render event (which is not an event in reality) which is getting executed first and then your button's render fires up which is causing visibility setting it back to false (as per dictated in markup). If you handle Button's render/prerender event and set visibility there then you should be good.

Code should look like below

```
    <asp:Button ID="myButton" runat="server" onprerender="myButton_PreRender" /> 

    protected void myButton_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Comment: I am using PreRender(I edited). Can you tell me how can I use buttons render/prerender event ?

Comment: When I tried to debug, the code comes in "myButton_PreRender" function but when I click the button, it does not come in "myButton_PreRender" function

Comment: That is because initially your button has visible=false which results in not generating html markup for your button. You can check it by making it visible=true.

Comment: The thing, is I have 2 buttons and I want only 1 button at the run time to be visible. So, if I keep Visible=True, when I declare, on page load only 1 button is visible and as i click on the button, both the buttons become visible.

Comment: Better option will be changing visibility using javascript. Initially keep it visible then make it invisible on document load and then based on your logic you can make it visible again.